# How to extract the first word of a vector of strings in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I have a dataset of companies name as below, I want to extract the first word(sometimes the second), how can I do this in Matlab. I think the idea might be telling Matlab to extract any non space letters till it encounters the first space, right? But how can I realise this idea? Thanks!

```
OLYMPUS CORPORATION
QUALCOMM INCORPORATED
CISCO TECHNOLOGY, INC.
SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD
INTERDIGITAL TECHNOLOGY CORPORATION
SUN MICROSYSTEMS, INC.
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit. So what should be the output for the input you gave? Is it going to be `OLYMPUS`? When should the program return the second word? Is the example you gave a 6x1 matrix, i.e. 6-length vector?

Comment: The output will be a vector of first word of all companies name like you said. Sometimes the companies keyname is the second word, I haven't think it through how to handle that kind of case yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[strtok](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html) is a Matlab function that does exactly this.

I can only *guess* that you've got a cell array of strings there, each line is an element of the cell array? So in your case you'd have something like this:

```
S = {'OLYMPUS CORPORATION';
     'QUALCOMM INCORPORATED'}

strtok(S{1})
```

Which outputs `OLYMPUS`

or if you want the first word of every line it's just

```
strtok(S)
```

outputs

```
OLYMPUS
QUALCOMM
```